# AS3 : How do I clear graphics in a specific pixel/area

Tags: actionscript-3, graphics, actionscript

I know that you use `graphics.clear` to clear all the graphics but that clears the graphics from the stage, I would like to clear graphics in a specific pixel(s) or between x-y value how do I do that?

Comment: Graphics are just numbers (for vector/shape points). You can only clear pixels in bitmaps. Use `draw` on the container (sprite/MC) of the graphics (vectors) to get a bitmap snapshot then you can simply use `setPixel` to set a "clearing" colour pixel.

Answer (score 7):

There's no way to do that with graphics. I just tried, drawing transparent shapes does not create holes, alas.

You should convert the graphics you have into Bitmap instance and work with pixels:

```
package
{
    import flash.geom.Matrix;
    import flash.geom.Rectangle;

    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.BitmapData;
    import flash.display.DisplayObject;

    public class Holey extends Sprite
    {
        public function Holey() 
        {
            super();

            // Lets create some example graphics.
            graphics.beginFill(0x990000);
            graphics.drawCircle(200, 200, 100);
            graphics.endFill();

            // Convert into raster and make 1 pixel transparent.
            var aBit:Bitmap = rasterize(this);
            aBit.bitmapData.setPixel32(50, 50, 0x00000000);

            graphics.clear();
            addChild(aBit);
        }

        private function rasterize(source:DisplayObject):Bitmap
        {
            // Obtain bounds of the graphics.
            var aBounds:Rectangle = source.getBounds(source);

            // Create raster of appropriate size.
            var aRaster:BitmapData = new BitmapData(aBounds.width, aBounds.height, true, 0x00000000);

            // Make an offset to capture all the graphics.
            var aMatrix:Matrix = new Matrix;
            aMatrix.translate(-aBounds.left, -aBounds.top);

            aRaster.draw(source, aMatrix);
            return new Bitmap(aRaster);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The way to do this would be [with a `mask`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e0b.html). Using an alpha mask (both mask and maskee use `cacheAsBitmap=true`) you can draw transparent pixels onto the mask to erase parts. The basic approach would be:

1. Put all your graphics that you want to be effected by the mask in a common container (if you mean for *everything* to be cut, then they are already in a common container: the `stage` or `root` timeline.)
2. Draw a bitmap data object that has a transparent "hole" in the area you want to erase. For example:

   ```
   // fill the stage with a solid rectangle
   var maskBitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight, true, 0xff000000);
   // erase part of it by drawing transparent pixels
   maskBitmapData.fillRect(new Rectangle(20, 20, 200, 100), 0);

   // create the mask object
   var maskBitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(maskBitmapData);
   maskBitmap.cacheAsBitmap = true; // this makes the mask an alpha mask
   addChild(maskBitmap);
   ```
3. Set the container's [`.mask` property](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#mask). For example, to mask the entire main timeline:

   ```
   root.cacheAsBitmap = true; // this makes the mask an alpha mask
   root.mask = maskBitmap;
   ```

Answer (score 3):

Open stack overflow to answer some questions, think for next hour about how holes are placed in cheese... :)

You could also set [blendMode](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#blendMode) property of your hole object to [BlendMode.ERASE](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BlendMode.html#ERASE) in combination with `cacheAsBitmap`. This works similar to masks except you would be actually drawing the wholes and not the area outside them.
Here is an example:

```
//make cheese
var cheese:Sprite = new Sprite();
cheese.cacheAsBitmap = true;
stage.addChild(cheese);
cheese.x = cheese.y = 10;

//define holes 
var holes:Shape = new Shape();
holes.blendMode = BlendMode.ERASE;
cheese.addChild(holes);

//draw cheese
var g = cheese.graphics;
g.beginFill(0xFFCC00);
g.drawRect(0,0,200,150);

//**Attack chees with mices.
g = holes.graphics;
for (var i:int = 0; i < 10; i++){
    g.beginFill(0xFF00FF);
    var hx = Math.random()*(cheese.width-7)+7;
    var hy = Math.random()*(cheese.height-7)+7;
    var s = Math.random()*15;
    g.drawCircle(hx, hy, s);
    g.endFill();
}
```

Result would be something like that:

[image]

**edit:**

Turns out that you don't need to use `cacheAsBitmap` if you set blend mode of parent object to `LAYER` (doc says it should be set automatically...)
So you can use `cheese.blendMode = BlendMode.LAYER;` instead of  `cheese.cacheAsBitmap = true;`. And if I remember correctly, masks also don't require `cahceAsBitmap`, even with `NORMAL` blending mode.

Comment: This idea is breathtakingly great! The only thing worries me though, will it cut holes down to the stage or only in underlying siblings within the same DisplayObjectContainer?

Comment: It only cuts holes in container. Note also that your `holes`  object have to be last child in this container